# .NET Core REST API Detect Put/Post Field From Request

Tags: rest, api, .net-core

I have an endpoint for create/update a data object that has 5 fields in its table.

There are 5 fields for creation:

```
class A
{
    string field1
    string field2
    int field3
    int field4
    bool field5
}
```

When a requester call my endpoint, I want to detect which fields posted in request body. Because i will use those posted fields for my update. I don't want to use other fields.

For ex: Requester has created a data with using 5 fields. After a while, requster just posted 3 fields those wanted to update. He doesn't want to update other 2 fields. So I need to detect which fields sent to endpoint and update only these 3 fields.

Answer (score 0):

When the client doesn't include one or more fields from your model, it's called "underposting." In that case, unless you've marked the missing fields as required (using an attribute), they will be set to the default value.

So, assuming you can set establish a "magic" default value for each field (a value that would not come from the client), you can determine which were sent by the client and which were not, and change your logic accordingly. For example:

```
class A {
  string field1 = "nosave";
  string field2 = "nosave";
  int field3 = -1;
  int field4 = -1;
  bool field5;
}

public IActionResult foo(A request) {
   if(request.A != "nosave") { saveField(request.A); }
   ...
}
```

The tricky part would be fields like Booleans, where no possible values can be ignored. For that, you could probably use a nullable field.

The alternative would be to have the client send, in addition to the fields, a list of fields that should be updated.